# Turn on control of antiparallel SCRs to pass AC

Tags: power-electronics, induction-motor, gate-driving, thyristor, scr

If you are trying to pass an AC signal through antiparallel SCRs (there to isolate the signal when required) where the AC frequency is low enough to satisfy the turn-off time requirements during the reverse biased half-cycle for each SCR, how do you keep the SCRs from turning off when you do not want them to?

Do controllers for these circuits typically send gate current pulses every single half-cycle to turn the SCRs back on? For some reason I was under the impression you send one "on signal" to both SCRs and they will stay on until you power off the AC or use a turn-off commutation method, but I think I have been incorrect and was hoping if someone can clarify if I am on the correct track now on how this setup is operated.

From what I understand the requirements to turn off the SCRS are fulfilled every half-cycle where the AC signal being passed is reverse biasing one of the SCRs.

1. The SCR will be reverse biased for 1/2 the period
2. The current will drop below the holding current for the appropriate turn off time.

Due to the above I assume before the next forward biased cycle you would have to send another gate pulse to turn on the SCR. So in order to keep both SCRs ON for when they need to conduct a pulse train of turn on signals would have to be applied to both SCRs at the frequency of the signal you are trying to pass and not just one signal at the start of operations.

Follow up question: Can I just keep a constant gate turn on current going into the SCR from the gatedriver if I dont want to have to time pulses? Or will not letting the SCR turn off during the half-cycles it isn't used cause issues?

Comment: What is the load that you are trying to control?

Comment: Induction Motor. AC is from an inverter

Comment: Why can't you just use the inverter to control the motor? Your problem is about 5 times more complicated now that you want to switch the inverter power - the inverter output is at least several kilohertz. Furthermore, the inverter isn't going to like seeing an SCR(s) between it and the motor. At best, it's going to give you faults/errors. At worse, you destroy the drive.

Comment: It's a pretty typical use of SCRs unsure of you just never heard of this use?

Comment: No it's not. All motor inverters have start, stop, current limits, torque control capability. Putting SCRs between a motor and inverter is atypical. To be honest, I don't know why you would want to do that. What are the SCR's going to achieve that your motor drive can't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do you keep the SCRs from turning off when you do not want them to?

You don't.  Once it is triggered, each SCR stays on for the remainder of its half-cycle.  It turns itself off at the zero-crossing.

> Do controllers for these circuits typically send gate current pulses every single half-cycle to turn the SCRs back on?

Yes.

> I was under the impression you send one "on signal" to both SCRs and they will stay on

If you mean "stay on" as in remain conducting for multiple AC cycles - No.

> From what I understand the requirements to turn off the SCRS are fulfilled every half-cycle where the AC signal being passed is reverse biasing one of the SCRs.  1. The SCR will be reverse biased for 1/2 the period.  2. The current will drop below the holding current for the appropriate turn off time.

Correct.

> before the next forward biased cycle you would have to send another gate pulse to turn on the SCR. So in order to keep both SCRs ON for when they need to conduct a pulse train of turn on signals would have to be applied to both SCRs at the frequency of the signal you are trying to pass and not just one signal at the start of operations.

Correct.

> Can I just keep a constant gate turn on current going into the SCR from the gatedriver if I dont want to have to time pulses?

Yes.  Things change if you are using the SCRs in a dimmer or motor speed controller, where the gate turn-on voltage or pulse is delayed for a portion of the half-cycle to limit the energy to the device.  For a simple on-off system such as a solid state relay, the gate voltage is derived from the AC waveform powering the load.  Coming up from a zero-crossing, the SCR is turned on as soon as the input AC reaches the trigger voltage level, usually 2-3 V.  Don't quote me on that number; check the datasheet for your device.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't described the characteristics of the line that you are switching. If you are switching something similar to a Sine, see below. If not, describe the characteristics of the inverter output.

I worked for a company that made high-power SCR phase controllers. They always had separate circuits for each anti-parallel SCR. The power for the gate pulse was from a transformer. Since the Cathodes are not common, separate circuits are required. The driving circuit created a strong fast rising pulse, that quickly decayed into a lower sustaining level that lasted until the end of the half cycle.

Some simpler circuits fire the gate from the voltage on the Anode. This will always be a pulse since when the SCR conducts the Anode voltage relative to the Cathode will drop to near zero.

You sometimes can keep the gate current on continuously, but for high-power circuits, you may have issues. If you are phase controlling, you need a strong gate signal to turn the SCR On completely in a very short time, otherwise you can stress the SCR. You will waste power creating the gate signal and your driver circuit will need to be large.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful! I was actually referring to a sinusoid. So you DO need to pulse each SCR every half cycle to keep them on if I properly understood the your explanation? And when you say separate circuitry for each SCR I assume you are referring to separate gate drivers.

Comment: OP days in other comments that the supply is from an inverter so we may not be dealing with a sinusoidal waveform.

Comment: Yes, you need a gate signal every half-cycle. The SCR will turn off when the current goes to zero (when the Anode is negative relative to the Cathode). Yes, separate gate drivers (gate signal is relative to the Cathode) since the Cathodes are at a much different potential.